# Share extension not working properly with ios 13

Tags: ios

Im using share extension for my application which was running smoothly before iOS 13. On release of iOS 13 it stopped working as in now when we press share button from safari, it opens up all applications where I can share the content. I locate my application and it shows options to share into but does not open further categories screen from which I can choose under which category I want to save the content. Anyone having an any idea on what changes for iOS 13 happened to cause the same would be a great help.